# Finite Morphisms of Affine Curves are Surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about a step used in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (see page 109):

[image]

The statement is that a ***finite morphism of integral affine curves is surjective***.

Indeed I'm familar with some proofs to show this statement but the point I'm really interested is concretely the argument given in this source by the author.

He claims that the ***Case 2*** of the proof of 4.3.5 cannot occure in the case of a finite morphism.

My question is why?

Here the proof of 4.3.5:

[image]

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, use that finite morphisms have finite fibers.

Comment: @SamirCanning: if we asseme the case $2$ then we deduce following the proof of 4.3.5 that the map is a constant map and with your argument $Y$ (=preimage) is a finite set. This contradicts that $Y$ was assumed to be a curve. Do you mean this argument?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument in the book is too complicated:
A finite morphism of schemes is a closed map, hence the image of Y is closed and irreducible in $X$ and thus that image is equal to $X$.
By the way, my argument does not use that $X$ or $Y$ is affine, nor that $Y$ has dimension $1$!

Comment: To prevent misunderstandings: I have only used that $Y$ is not a point (in order that its irreducible image not be a point in $X$) but in fact $Y$ **must**  *a posteriori* have dimension one,  because dimension is preserved under finite surjective morphisms.

Comment: how do you excluded that the given finite morphism isn't constant? I don't see how conclude that without using the fact that finite morphisms have finite fibers

Comment: Dear Karl, indeed you have to know that finite morphisms have finite fibers. By the way in algebraic geometry you have the completely general  characterization for morphisms: **finite = proper with finite fibers** (The same result is also true for holomorphic morphisms between complex analytic varieties)